# How to access json data from kohana?

Tags: php, json, kohana

I write simple function to list data for web service request.

I try to access data in my controller like this.

```
public function action_ListData() {
    var_dump($this->request->post("jsondata"));
    die();
}
```

This is my json.

```
{  
   "jsondata":
{  
    "id" : "1234"
    }
}
```

I can't access json data.
It prints empty array.
how can I access the data?
Please advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to `json_decode()` your data first?

Comment: No.after I changed the line var_dump($this->request->post()); to var_dump(json_decode($this->request->post())); is prints NULL insted of empty array.

Comment: this means that your request fails and is unable to fetch/get any data at all.

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '',$this->request->post()), true));`

Comment: @NishantSolanki still not working

Comment: @andrew how can I fix this?

Comment: @IshaS no idea my friend. You need to debug your code and find where the error/bug is happening. Although i find somewhat suspicious that your `$this->request->post("jsondata")` is using `post`. Perhaps you send you data and you get no reply? Or you need to `get` your data?

Answer (score 1):

`request->post()` is for getting form encoded data like `jsondata={"id":"1234"}` but your entire request body is a JSON payload, so you should use this:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($this->request->body(), true);
var_dump($data);
```